# Scrollbar is not working in WPF list box

Tags: wpf, listbox, scrollbar

There is a problem with my application to include a scrollbar in the list box. I checked some related questions here but they didn't solve my problem.  The list box shows the scroll bar but it seems kind of disabled.What is wrong with my code?

```
<Grid>
<ListBox Name="ToursListBox" MinHeight="200"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"
               MinWidth="300"
               Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="10" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Can you see both of the scrollbar arrow buttons, or is one of them pushed out of sight?

Comment: @EdPlunkett, I can only see the top arrow of the scrollbar!

Comment: Usually the problem with Scroll is due to the container in which it is inserted allow infinite size, and therefore it does not appear. Possibly you can correct this by setting a `MaxHeight` or `Height` to your Grid, or to your ListBox. PS.: `Height` can be relative

Comment: @nassertahani That makes sense. The ListBox is taller than its parent. If the Grid is less than 200 pixels (or whatever units) high, the solution might even be as simple as removing `MinHeight="200"` from the ListBox. But if that doesn't work, I'd need to see the whole XAML context, all the parents. Then I could figure out where things went wrong.

Comment: @CelsoLívero thanks, changing MinWidth to MaxWidth solved my problem.